# multiplexing of multiple Bluetooth headset microphones

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, headset

I would like to multiplex inputs of multiple Bluetooth headset microphones. Is it possible on any platform - RasPi, Android, iOS, Windows? I was already successful with one Bluetooth headset and Raspberry Pi Bluez stack.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION AS SUGGESTED:
I would like to have one device (preferably a smartphone, I'll call it broker) which is connected to multiple headsets (containing a microphone). Headsets are located in different rooms, the single broker receives all the sound streams from the microphones via Bluetooth and process this information. The clue would be - the headsets are cheap, I would not have to invest heavily into the hardware to hear all the sounds at home. It's an R&D project.

Comment: Explain in brief buddy or put your r&d part something.

Comment: Please add in more details so other can help